# Using JSNI to create Labeled Marker cause Object function MarkerLabel_(marker, crossURL, handCursorURL){ ...} has no method 'getSharedCross'

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3, jsni

I tried to create a **Label Marker** by using **JSNI** to call **google-maps-utility-library-v3 's markerwithlabel.js** . However, I always receive this exception :

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) @com.gwt.map.client.GWTMap::setLabeledMarker(Lcom/google/gwt/maps/client/base/LatLng;Lcom/google/gwt/maps/client/MapImpl;)([JavaScript object(51), JavaScript object(19)]): Object function MarkerLabel_(marker, crossURL, handCursorURL){ ...} has no method 'getSharedCross'
```

Here is the JSNI method I have created :

```
    public final native void setLabeledMarker(LatLng ll,MapImpl myMap)
/*-{
   var marker = new $wnd.MarkerWithLabel({
   position: ll,
   draggable: true,
   raiseOnDrag: true,
   labelContent: "Hello",
   labelAnchor: new $wnd.google.maps.Point(22, 0),
   labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
   labelStyle: {opacity: 1.0}
 });

 marker.setMap(myMap);
}-*/;
```

I'm using [Branflake's GWT Map version 3.8.1](https://github.com/branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api) and [google-maps-utility-library-v3 's markerwithlabel.js](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.7/src/)

Please give me your advise

Answer (score 0):

How are you loading the markerwithlabel.js script? You should load it dynamically after the google maps API library by attaching a script element to the DOM.